# Multi-Threading Freezing up

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn how to properly use multi-threading and for some reason my code keeps freezing after one iteration through updating my `progressbar`. I've got the `progressbar` setup correctly because I've tested that on the side. I thought I had my multi-threading correct but the two classes dont seem to be communicating right. Can anyone with a trained eye spot my error here? Thank you

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class ProgressBar {

    static int j = 0;
    static int n = 0;

    synchronized public static void main(String args[]) {

        double percent = .01;

        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("pick a really big number for no reason"));

        //this block is just the progress bar   
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Progress Bar");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = f.getContentPane();
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Reading...");
        progressBar.setBorder(border);
        content.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setSize(300, 100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        //this block is just the progress bar

        Computation c = new Computation();
        c.start();

        while(percent <= 1.0){
            if( j >= (n*percent) ){

                progressBar.setValue((int) (percent*100));
                progressBar.repaint();
                percent += .01;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
    }


    public static class Computation extends Thread{

        synchronized public void run(){
            while( j < n ){
                j++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks like your 'j' variable is out of scope on your thread. is class Computation in the same class as your main()? the formatting makes it difficult to tell.

Comment: OH, I see what happend...let me edit that for you :)

Comment: `percent` never changes, its a constant, and you are printing it instead of printing the progress.

Comment: Why did you synchronized the main method? Do you think is it possible that more than one thread can get the lock for main method? Main method is the start of all threads in you app and synchronizing it is meaningless.

Comment: Like i said I'm new at this. @ STaefi

Comment: @Havenard I've got my `percent` incrementing by .01 inside the `while` loop which updates my progress bar

Comment: Thats a pretty weird way of doing that. And whats the maximum value of `JProgressBar` anyway, you are not defining it as far as I can see. And I don't get why you even have a `percent` variable.

Comment: The funny thing is, I think the repaint is the only thing keeping the compiler from literally deleting the entire block in favor of optimization... (if the compiler can determine end state of a loop block, it will eleminate the loop and just assign the end state unless the changing value affects something external to the loop)

Comment: Try `progressBar.setMaximum(n)` when initializing your progress bar, then `progressBar.setValue(j)` to update progress. Drop that `percent` variable, and just check `while(j < n)` instead. It makes no sense what you are doing with that `percent`.

Comment: any ideas on why the threads aren't communicating properly?

Comment: essentially.. why the main thread isn't reading the updated j value from the new thread i initialized...

Comment: This will never work correctly, independent of other threads/issues, because you are incorrectly working with Swing.

Comment: how would i correctly work with swing in this instance? do you have any recommendations?

Comment: All Swing UI updates/access should be done on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and the EDT must be allowed to run freely. This particular example is plagued by that; and several other problems 1) the 'main' loop runs too fast, so you're *just jamming the Swing system* and 2) *there is no guaranteed thread-visibility of the variables* as they are not volatile. Writing to stdout - and bypassing Swing issues - would at least make the initial threading problem(s) a bit easier to identify instead of 'freezing up'.

Comment: so because J is being accessed by the EDT, its being blocked by my new thread which is holding it hostage essentially?

Comment: `j` is not a Swing/UI control so.. no.

Comment: The latest value of `j` is not guaranteed to be seen by other threads, the usage of synchronized is incorrect here. One solution is to simply make `j` volatile, or to add synchronized blocks using the same lock over the write of `j` and the read of `j`.

Comment: making `j` volatile fixed it right away! thank you so much. No idea what that does and/or is but I'll be looking into it for certain.

Comment: I'll check into my synchronization of my classes tomorrow some more. thank you for the quick fix for tonight though! @NESPowerGlove

Comment: @DojoOria No problem. So that was the issue?

Comment: Making j volatile or atomic is a bad choice since the main thread would spin like crazy. Synchronization is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the access to the shared data. The synchronization need to be done using the same object. Here is one solution, maybe not the best but at least it works. Also note the loop surrounding the wait. This is typical, to check whether you have met the condition to carry on.

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;

public class ProgressBar {

    static final Object lock = new Object();

    static int j = 0;
    static int n = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        double percent = .01;

        n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("pick a really big number for no reason"));

        //this block is just the progress bar
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Progress Bar");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = f.getContentPane();
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Reading...");
        progressBar.setBorder(border);
        content.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setSize(300, 100);
        f.setVisible(true);
        //this block is just the progress bar

        Computation c = new Computation();
        c.start();

        while (percent <= 1.0) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (j < n * percent) {
                    lock.wait();
                }
            }

            progressBar.setValue((int) (percent * 100));
            progressBar.repaint();
            percent += .01;
        }
    }


    public static class Computation extends Thread {

        public void run(){
            while(true) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    if (j >= n) break;
                    j++;
                    lock.notify();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well likely you've moved the synchronization point from the `run()` method to an inner point. Certainly in your code the granulation is better, but is this the reason of the behavior change?

Comment: yes, first the lock is on the same object, and if that had been the case in the original code then one thread  had to complete (main) before the other one started. The wait call release the lock temporarily and let the other thread run. Locking around the data access enforced some changes to the logic. (The result is undefined if you don't lock on the same object.)